# DateDiff in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

How to use Datediff (of MySQL) in Hibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this can help : https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2393545

Answer (score 1):

Better implement your own dialect. Something like this

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class MsSqlDialect extends SQLServerDialect {
    public MsSqlDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("DATEDIFF", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "dateDiff(", ",", ")"));
    }
}
```